# Convert dates from XLS into R

Tags: r, excel

I import dates from Excel into R.
Some of the values appear as real numbers:
e.g. 43313.458055555559
I would like to convert these numbers into a
timestamp representation like this - 9/4/2018 11:45:35AM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the Other Applications section of the Help Desk article in R News 4/1 https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Duplicate as search shows options using date time packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093228/convert-excel-numeric-to-and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-with-lubridate

Comment: Based on G. Grothendieck's comment, try: `as.POSIXct(as.Date(43313.458055555559, origin = "1899-12-30"))`

Comment: @ANG could you convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Excel numeric to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093228/convert-excel-numeric-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on G. Grothendieck's comment, try:

`as.POSIXct(as.Date(43313.458055555559, origin = "1899-12-30"))`

Just replace `43313.458055555559` by `DataFrame.name$Column.name`.

> **Spreadsheets like Microsoft Excel on a Windows PC or OpenOffice.org
>   represent datetimes as days and fraction of days since December 30,
>   1899 (usually)**. If `x` is a vector of such numbers then
>   `as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(x)` will give a vector of Date class
>   dates with respect to Date’s origin. Similarly `chron("12/30/1899") + x`
>   will give chron dates relative to chron’s origin. **Excel on a Mac
>   usually represents dates as days and fraction of days since January 1,
>   1904** so `as.Date("1904-01-01") + floor(x)` and `chron("01/01/1904") + x` convert vectors of numbers representing such dates to Date and chron respectively. Its possible
>   to set Excel to use either origin which is why the word usually was
>   employed above.
>
> Source: https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf